# Smallest prime factor of a Mersenne number

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

The Mersenne numbers $M_n$ are integers of the form $2^n-1$, where $n$ is a positive integer. In the case when $n$ is a prime, are there any results known on the smallest prime factor, $p_n$, of $M_n$, as a function of $n$? I've seen some papers on the *largest* prime factor, see here for instance

https://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/PDF/murata4.pdf

but nothing yet on smallest. I'm especially interested in knowing whether $p_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$ for $n$ prime? Thank you.

Comment: You may want to restrict $n$ to be a prime number, otherwise you have e.g. $p_{2k} = 3$ and in general if $q$ is smallest prime factor of $n = qk$ then $p_{qk} \leq p_q$. This follows since $2^{qk}-1$ is divisible by $2^q-1$.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting. I've now edited the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Wikpedia: "If p is an odd prime, then every prime q that divides $2^p − 1$ must be 1 plus a multiple of 2p"

So the smallest possible number dividing $2^p − 1$ is $2p+1$ which obviously goes to infinity as p does.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime#Theorems_about_Mersenne_numbers

Answer (score 0):

The question seems to be related to the [Mersenne conjectures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_conjectures). We restrict ourselfs to $n=p$ prime.
If there are infinitely many Mersenne primes $M_p$, then the least prime divisor of $M_p$ would be $M_p$ itself infinitely often. On the other hand, the least prime factor seems to be much smaller than $M_p$ infinitely often, too.

Comment: Thanks for the two answers. I'm especially interested in knowing whether $p_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$ for $n$ prime.

Comment: Thanks again. From your answer, perhaps it would be better (at least for now) if one can show there is an infinite subset $S \subset \mathbb{N}$ such that, for each prime $p \in S$, the smallest prime factor of $M_p$ is $\geq p^{1 + \epsilon}$ for some $\epsilon > 0$. See Theorem 3 in the paper cited above. It assumes GRH. Since the authors in that paper were more interested in the largest prime divisor, I wonder if this can be proven, without GRH, for the smallest prime factor? Maybe not..?

Answer (score 0):

Taking @dioid's comment further, we know that for a prime $p\neq 2$ we have $p|2^{p-1}-1$ so that $p|2^{n(p-1)}-1$

If $q_p$ is the least exponent for which $p|2^{q_p}-1$, then it is easy to show that $p|2^q-1$ only if $q_p|q$

So if $q>q_3, q_5, q_7 \dots q_p$ is a prime, then no prime $\leq p$ can be a factor of $2^q-1$